# Disable camelcase rule for identifier in specifics interfaces

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I use the [@typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint) plugin to add rules to my TypeScript code using eslint.

One of the rules that I have enabled is [camelcase](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/camelcase.md):

```
"@typescript-eslint/camelcase": ["error", { "properties": "always" }]
```

It allows me to normalize my variable and interfaces names.

Problem is that the standard JSON format uses the snake_case convention to name their identifier. So all my API requests response are using snake_case.

In this case, I have to declare interfaces using snake_case like that:

```js
interface UserResponse {
  id: number
  dark_mode: boolean
  status_code: string
}
```

So my question is: Is there a way to disable this rule for identifier defined in an interface ending width `Response`? So there are no lint errors in my `UserResponse` interface.

@typescript-eslint provide an interesting parameter [allow](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/camelcase.md#allow) that disable the rule for specific names matching a regex:

```js
/* @typescript-eslint/camelcase: ["error", {allow: ["Response$"]}] */

interface Foo_Bar_Response {
  ...
}
```

Here the linter will not trigger the snake_case format from `Foo_Bar_Response` because it's ending with the word `Response`.

But here it only works for the name of the interface itself and not for the names of these child identifiers.

Any idea how we can make this work?

Answer (score 0):

its a closed issue on github https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2077 you can try to fix on the codebase which is not recommended.
you can also try to disable with the options: based on use case of camelcased vars or interfaces props of your project https://eslint.org/docs/rules/camelcase